# Using PowerShell script, Ping a list of host names and output the results to a csv

Tags: powershell

I have a large list of hostnames I need to ping to see if they are pinging or not. I am new at scripting but I managed to figure this much out but getting error when I run this script, I run the script using "PowerShell.exe script.ps > output.csv".

Error Below:

```
"pinghost.ps : The term 'pinghost.ps' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet  function    script file     or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name  or if a path was included   verify that the path is correct and try again. 
At line:1 char:1            
#NAME?          
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~           
    + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (pinghost.ps:String) []  CommandNotFoundException       
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException  :"
```

Code below:

```
$names = Get-content ".\hnames.txt"

foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name,up"
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$name,down"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with a qualified file path: `powershell.exe C:\path\to\pinghost.ps1`?

Comment: Also the script doesn't close or end after all the VMs are pinged , not sure what is missing it keeps on running, is there something missing in the script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell will attempt to resolve unqualified file paths passed as command line arguments *relative to its **working directory*** - if you launch PowerShell from the Run prompt or as a scheduled task running as a specific local user account, the working directory will default to the users profile folder.

Either pass a rooted file path:

```
powershell.exe -File C:\Users\Akshay\path\to\pinghost.ps1
```

Or a file path that's relative to the expected working directory (using `/` instead of `\` will prevent PowerShell from interpreting the path as a module-qualified command name):

```
powershell.exe -File path/to/pinghost.ps1
```

In order to make PowerShell's provider cmdlets correctly resolve the `hnames.txt` file relative to the location of the script itself, prepend the path with the `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable:

```
$names = Get-content (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot hnames.txt)

foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Write-Host "$name,up"
  }
  else{
    Write-Host "$name,down"
  }
}
```

Now it will work as long as the script and text file are in the same directory, regardless of where you call it from.